# Hibernate and multiple threads, synchronize changes between multiple users

Tags: database, multithreading, hibernate, eclipse-rap

I am using Hibernate in an Eclipse RAP application. I have database tables mapped to classes with Hibernate and these classes have properties that are fetched lazily (If these weren't fetched lazily then I would probably end up loading the whole database into memory on my first query). I do not synchronize database access so there are multiple Hibernate `Sessions` for the users and let the DBMS do the transaction isolation. This means different instances of fetched data will belong to different users. There are things that if a user changes those things, then I would like to update those across multiple users. Currently I was thinking about using Hibernate `session.refresh(object)` in these cases to refresh the data, but I'm unsure how this will impact performance when refreshing multiple objects or if it's the right way to go.

Hope my problem is clear. Is my approch to the problem OK or is it fundamentally flawed or am I missing something? Is there a general solution for this kind of problem?

I would appreciate any comments on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is

- to have transactions as short as possible
- to link the session lifecycle to the transaction lifecycle (this is the default: the session is closed when the transaction is committed or rolled back)
- to use optimistic locking concurrency to avoid two transactions updating the same object at the same time.

If each transaction is very short and transaction A updates some object from O to O', then concurrent transaction B will only see O until it commits or rolls back, and any other transaction started after A will see O', because a new session starts with the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

We maintain an application that does exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Yes, every session.refresh() will hit the database, but since all sessions will refresh the same row at the same time, the DB server will answer all of these queries from memory.

The only thing that you still need to solve is how to propagate the information that something has changed and needs reloading to all the other sessions, possibly even to sessions on a different host.

For our application, we have about 30 users on RCP and 10-100 users on RAP instances that all connect to the very same DB backend (though through pgpool). We use a small network service that every runtime connects to; when a transaction commits, the application tells this change service that "row id X of table T" has changed and this is then propagated to all other "change subscribers", even across JVMs.

**But: make sure that session.refresh() is called within the Thread that belongs to that session,** possibly the RAP-Display thread. Do not call refresh() from Jobs or other unrelated threads.

As long you don't have a large number of users updating big counts of rows in short time, I guess you won't have to worry about performance.